# Modelling Flat Surfaces and Wall Corners With Megascans Textures

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, edges, geometry

I am new at 3d environment modelling. I am using Megascans for textures. I have a problem with modelling corners of building and variation on flat surfaces. How can ı add geometry over texture?

Examples of what I want to do:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the texture displacement/height texture?

Comment: No. They are not displaced geometry. They are modelled over 2d texture I think. They have less triss than displaced surfaces.

Comment: Are you looking for an automated way to get low poly geometry to add 3D detail to a textured object? If not, the answer would be the same as how to make any other textured object.

Comment: Yes. I am looking for how to add detail to a textured object.

Comment: @Ytwenty  Manually?

Comment: Manually or automatic, it doesn't matter how. I cant find any tutorial and breakdown about that.